# Expectation of $\int_0^t X(r) \, dW(r)$ where $dX=\mu \, dt+\sigma \, dW$

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-calculus

I have a questionlike:
if $dX=\mu \, dt+\sigma \, dW$, where $W$ is a standard B.m. Then, is this expectation still o,$\int_0^t X(r) \, dW(r)$  ?
Thank you all.

Comment: What do _you_ think? Can you quote properties of Ito integral? When is the expectation of the Ito integral defined?

Comment: Are $\mu, \sigma$ constants or stochastic processes?  If the latter, what do you know about them?